# AWS Iot sdk javascript - Cannot connect to AWS (Failed to read credentials for AWS_PROFILE default from undefined)

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-iot, aws-sdk-js

I am trying with no luck to connect with websockets to aws iot with aws-iot-sdk. I'm getting the error "Failed to read credentials for AWS_PROFILE default from undefined" on browser console + "To connect via WebSocket/SigV4, AWS Access Key ID and AWS Secret Key must be passed either in options or as environment variables; see README.md" +
"Uncaught Error: Invalid connect options supplied."

It's my first time posting here, so please be patience if you think my way of describing isn't good:(

Btw i have set all the required credentials right according to this example[enter link description here](https://github.com/serverless-guru/real-time-weather/blob/master/README.md)
I gave admin privileges to IAM user too.

Comment: if you did what was described in the link, then it should  work. If you could post a minimal reproducible code example, it would be easier to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can run CLI commands then execute `aws sts get-caller-identity` and it will show you the user of current session. You can also echo `AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE` to verify if the profile you selected is correct one.